# Crash on converting Dictionary to Json String

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to convert my swift dictionary to Json string but getting strange crash by saying

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue)'**

```
let parameterDictionary = ["id": "29091600104", "identifier": "1242323", "guestId":"123455", "ownedId": "234567"]
    var jsonString = ""
    do {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameterDictionary, options: .prettyPrinted)
        if let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as? String {
            jsonString = string
        }
    } catch {
        Print("Error serializing to JSON")
    }
```

I have tried searching online but haven't found anything useful.

Comment: Your code is working fine, just change from `Print` to `print`in the catch statement. Otherwise I got the result printed, make sure that you don´t have other stuff that Xcode complains about.

Comment: @Arun Kumar : I had also this crash. Did you solved this problem?